# How to prepopulate a node reference field (checkbox)

Tags: 7, nodes

On a node/add page I have a node reference. The widget type is "checkboxes" and I'm using the "View used to select the nodes" feature to show up to 5 checkboxes on the node/add page.

I would like to prepopulate a checkbox with the [prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

The checkboxes use this HTML name value:

```
name="field_tribe_content[und][18824]"
```

Usually prepopulate works by adding this to the url, but it doesn't work in this case.

`?edit[field_tribe_content][und]=18824`

There is some info in the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/422764) and I have also tried

```
?edit[field_tribe_content][0][nid]=18824
?edit[field_tribe_content][0][nid][nid]=18824
?edit[field_tribe_content][nid][nid]=18824
```

How can I get it to work or what else could I do to preopulate those checkboxes?

Comment: I never used prepopulate module so i'm not sur about my answer. But i often passed a value on my form to my node reference on a module like this: `$form['field_node_reference']["und"][0]['nid'] = array( "#type" => 'value', "#value" => $product->nid, );` Maybe try this path `?edit[field_tribe_content]["und"][0]['nid']` to prepopulate your checkbox

Comment: thanks, that didn't do it either. I think because of the checkbox widget the prepopulate module would have to add a checked="checked" to the HTML and not just modify the value. I don't think it can do that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

[Prepopulate checkbox [#checked]](http://drupal.org/node/1386072)

I have also been searching for a solution on how to do this.

Comment: that patch worked for me